# Importing self-made package

Tags: python

I am testing my own package, but I am struggling to import it. My package file structure is as follows:

[image: File Structure]

(You can also alternatively view my Github repository [here](https://github.com/WillWammer/PyAdventures))

In PyAdventures is my **init**.py with the content of

```
name="pyadventures"
```

So my question is, when I import it in another python file, how come it doesn't work?

I run:

```
import pyadventures
```

But I get the following error:

```
No module named pyadventures
```

It'd be great if you could answer my question!

> It's important to note that the package is in my Python package directory, not the test one I showed

New discovery! In my PyAdventures folder (the one Python actually uses) the folder only has a few files, not the ones in the screenshot above.

[image: New Discovery]

You can install this with `pip install pyadventures`

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of `__init__.py`, and you should read how to use [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). I would suggest to just put all the functions and classes that you defined in a file and call it mylibrary.py, and use it with `from mylibrary import MyClass` or `from mylibrary import my_function` until you become more familiar and proficient with python.

Comment: @hcheung I did in fact follow the Python docs for packaging

Comment: Well, that is not the way how it works.

Comment: The only other thing I see is that your file is in camel caps PyAdventures vs your import, which is pyadventures.

Comment: Read [this](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html) and [What is __ init __.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, like others remark in comments and answer: The camelcase might be the problem. (Why not name it just all in lower case: `pyadventures`? - Else users will be as confused as its developer now :D .)

Before, I thought, it might be a problem that you want to use your module without having installed it (locally). And my following answer is for this case (using a not installed package from a local folder):

In the docs you can read:

> The variable sys.path is a list of strings that determines the
>   interpreter’s search path for modules. It is initialized to a default
>   path taken from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, or from a
>   built-in default if PYTHONPATH is not set. You can modify it using
>   standard list operations:
>
> `import sys
>   sys.path.append('/ufs/guido/lib/python')`

thus, before import do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/absolute/or/relative/path/to/your/module/pyadventures')
# Now, your module is "visible" for the module loader
import pyadventures
```

Alternatively, you could just place your pyadventures module folder locally in your working directory where you start python and then just do

```
import pyadventures
```

However, it is much easier to manage to keep only one version in one place and refer to this from other places/scripts. (Else you have multiple copies, and have difficulties to track changes on the multiple copies).

As far as I know, your `__init__.py` doesn't need to contain anything. It works if it is empty. It is there just to mark your directory as a module.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Even though the package listed on pip is namd `pyadventures`, in your code the directory is called `PyAdventures`. So that's what python knows it as. I ran  `import PyAdventures` and it worked fine.